# I have an Ubuntu option on boot, but Ubuntu is not installed and I want to get rid of it

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8, uninstall

My laptop originally came with Windows 8, a while back I tried to install Ubuntu, but it didn't work so I just deleted everything. Today I did a factory reset on my laptop because I am going to sell it, but when I boot it boots to a black screen that says "GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.1" followed by a bunch of text. To access Windows 8 I have to hold down f11 on boot where I get the option for windows boot manager. I want to make Windows 8 the default, how to I get rid of this "ghost" ubuntu?

Comment: Is system set for UEFI boot? If Ubuntu was installed in UEFI mode you have to also delete ubuntu folder in efi partition and entry in UEFI. Details here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to askubuntu.

Use windows8 cd or live usb and go to windows repair. Select repair using cmd or command prompt. At command prompt type the below commands.

> Bootrec/fixmbr
>
> Bootrec/fixboot

Restart windows normally.